# Wordpress: how to call a plugin function with an ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm writing a Wordpress MU plugin, it includes a link with each post and I want to use ajax to call one of the plugin functions when the user clicks on this link, and then dynamically update the link-text with output from that function.

I'm stuck with the ajax query. I've got this complicated, clearly hack-ish, way to do it, but it is not quite working. What is the 'correct' or 'wordpress' way to include ajax functionality in a plugin?

(My current hack code is below. When I click the generate link I don't get the same output I get in the wp page as when I go directly to sample-ajax.php in my browser.)

I've got my code[1] set up as follows:

mu-plugins/sample.php:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Sample Plugin
*/
if (!class_exists("SamplePlugin")) {
  class SamplePlugin {
    function SamplePlugin() {}
    function addHeaderCode() {
      echo '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="'.get_bloginfo('wpurl').
             '/wp-content/mu-plugins/sample/sample.css" />\n';
      wp_enqueue_script('sample-ajax', get_bloginfo('wpurl') .
             '/wp-content/mu-plugins/sample/sample-ajax.js.php',
             array('jquery'), '1.0');

    }
    // adds the link to post content.
    function addLink($content = '') {
        $content .= "<span class='foobar clicked'><a href='#'>click</a></span>";
        return $content;
    }
    function doAjax() { //
        echo "<a href='#'>AJAX!</a>";
    } 
  }
}
if (class_exists("SamplePlugin")) {
  $sample_plugin = new SamplePlugin();
}
if (isset($sample_plugin)) {
  add_action('wp_head',array(&$sample_plugin,'addHeaderCode'),1);
  add_filter('the_content', array(&$sample_plugin, 'addLink'));
}
```

mu-plugins/sample/sample-ajax.js.php:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('add_action')) {
    require_once("../../../wp-config.php");
}
?>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".foobar").bind("click", function() {
        var aref = this;
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('clicked');
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: "http://mysite/wp-content/mu-plugins/sample/sample-ajax.php",
          success: function(value) {
            jQuery(aref).html(value);
          }
        });
    });
});
```

mu-plugins/sample/sample-ajax.php:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('add_action')) {
  require_once("../../../wp-config.php");
}
if (isset($sample_plugin)) {
  $sample_plugin->doAjax();
} else {
  echo "unset";
}
?>
```

**[1] Note:** The following tutorial got me this far, but I'm stumped at this point.
http://www.devlounge.net/articles/using-ajax-with-your-wordpress-plugin

Answer (score 24, accepted):

TheDeadMedic is not quite right. WordPress has built in AJAX capabilities. Send your ajax request to /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php using POST with the argument 'action':

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".foobar").bind("click", function() {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('clicked');
        jQuery.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          data:{action:'my_unique_action'},
          url: "http://mysite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
          success: function(value) {
            jQuery(this).html(value);
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Then hook it in the plugin like this if you only want it to work for logged in users:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_unique_action',array($sample_plugin,'doAjax'));
```

or hook it like this to work only for non-logged in users:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_unique_action',array($sample_plugin,'doAjax'));
```

Use both if you want it to work for everybody.

admin-ajax.php uses some action names already, so make sure you look through the file and don't use the same action names, or else you'll accidentally try to do things like delete comments, etc.

EDIT

Sorry, I didn't quite understand the question. I thought you were asking how to do an ajax request. Anyway, two things I'd try:

First, have your function echo just the word AJAX without the `a` tag. Next, try changing your ajax call so it has both a success and a complete callback:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".foobar").bind("click", function() {
        var val = '';
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('clicked');
        jQuery.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          data:{action:'my_unique_action'},
          url: "http://mysite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
          success: function(value) {
            val = value;
          },
          complete: function(){
            jQuery(this).html(val);
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I forgot to add that admin-ajax.php takes care of loading the whole WordPress environment, so you don't need to worry about including any files in your plugin.

Comment: Your original answer was great. Thanks for showing me the correct way to do ajax in wp. Your explanation makes clear what I've seen in other code I've read.

Note: I also had a javascript scoping error that I corrected above in the question, so it could be a more useful wp reference question than a 'fix my specific dumb bug' question. (was referencing 'this' inside the success fn for the ajax call).

Comment: John P is dead right, I do apologize, my solution is **not** the only way, but it's a method I find easy for quick AJAX, without having to load WordPress myself.

Comment: Forgot to mention in John P's method you can use the JavaScript variable `ajaxurl` rather than hardcoding the URL (or the property `userSettings.ajaxurl` in WP 3.0).

Comment: Where should I put the jQuery function ?, in which file ?

Answer (score 5):

**WordPress environment**

First of all, in order to achieve this task, it's recommended to register then enqueue a jQuery script that will push the request to the server. These operations will be hooked in `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook. In the same hook you should put `wp_localize_script` that it's used to include arbitrary Javascript. By this way there will be a JS object available in front end. This object carries on the correct url to be used by the jQuery handle.

Please take a look to:

1. [wp_register_script();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) function
2. [wp_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook
3. [wp_enqueue_script();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function
4. [wp_localize_script();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) function

**File: functions.php 1/2**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_enqueue_scripts' );
function so_enqueue_scripts(){
  wp_register_script( 'ajaxHandle', get_template_directory() . 'PATH TO YOUR JS FILE', array(), false, true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxHandle' );
  wp_localize_script( 'ajaxHandle', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
```

**File: jquery.ajax.js**

This file makes the ajax call.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
  //Some event will trigger the ajax call, you can push whatever data to the server, simply passing it to the "data" object in ajax call
  $.ajax({
    url: ajax_object.ajaxurl, // this is the object instantiated in wp_localize_script function
    type: 'POST',
    data:{
      action: 'myaction', // this is the function in your functions.php that will be triggered
      name: 'John',
      age: '38'
    },
    success: function( data ){
      //Do something with the result from server
      console.log( data );
    }
  });
});
```

**File: functions.php 2/2**

Finally on your functions.php file there should be the function triggered by your ajax call.
Remember the suffixes:

1. wp_ajax ( allow the function only for registered users or admin panel operations )
2. wp_ajax_nopriv ( allow the function for no privilege users )

These suffixes plus the action compose the name of your action:

`wp_ajax_myaction` or `wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction`

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myaction', 'so_wp_ajax_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction', 'so_wp_ajax_function' );
function so_wp_ajax_function(){
  //DO whatever you want with data posted
  //To send back a response you have to echo the result!
  echo $_POST['name'];
  echo $_POST['age'];
  wp_die(); // ajax call must die to avoid trailing 0 in your response
}
```

Hope it helps!

Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction', 'so_wp_ajax_function' );

Comment: very well explained.. I'm making my one of the first plugin and this is cool!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an information.
If you want to receive an object from a php class method function :

**js file**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".foobar").bind("click", function() {
    var data = {
        'action': 'getAllOptionsByAjax',
        'arg1': 'val1',
        'arg2': $(this).val() 
    };
    jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
       var jsonObj = JSON.parse( response );
    });
});
```

**php file**

```
public static function getAllOptionsByAjax(){

    global $wpdb;

    // Start query string
    $query_string  =  "SELECT * FROM wp_your_table WHERE col1='" . $_POST['arg1'] . "' AND col2 = '" . $_POST['arg2'] . "' ";

    // Return results
    $a_options = $wpdb->get_results( $query_string, ARRAY_A );
    $f_options = array();
    $f_options[null] =  __( 'Please select an item', 'my_domain' );
    foreach ($a_options as $option){
        $f_options [$option['id']] = $option['name'];
    }
    $json = json_encode( $f_options );
    echo $json;
    wp_die();
}
```