# Where to put form processing php file in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to create a simple chat in wordpress, and I don't want to use any plugins. I am creating the index file by myself and in there, I have a javascript function where it calls a jQuery's post method like the following:

```
    function chatinitial(){
        var user=document.getElementById("chatuser").value;
        jQuery.post("chat.php",/*{stage:"initial",user:user},*/function(data){
            alert(data);
        });

    }
```

In here, I need to call the chat.php to process my inputs, but I don't know where to put the chat.php file and how to point to it in the javascript code above. Do I put it in the theme folder?

Comment: You will have to use wp ajax functionality. Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908823/wordpress-how-to-call-a-plugin-function-with-an-ajax-call

Comment: you need to place under root folder.. For simple scenario, whereever your index.html exists..

Comment: @Samir he don't want to use plugins according to explanation

Comment: It would not be good idea to hack wp such way. Anyway if you really want that just put your file on the root directory as @SunilBN said.

Comment: If I place it at the root directory, what do I write? just jQuery("chat.php"?

Comment: yes, only the file name

Comment: you dont use ajax with wordpress in the same way, google wordpress ajax, it has a handler for ajax requests that you hook functions to from functions.php. SO you need to change the url above and change your file into a function.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `chat.php` in your root folder and change your JavaScript to:

`jQuery.post("/chat.php",`

Or put `chat.php` in your themes directory and change your JavaScript to:

`jQuery.post("/wp-content/themes/your_theme_name/chat.php",`

The second version would be my preference, the only downside being that the JavaScript is then tied to your theme name, so it will break if ever you rename your theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it quick and dirty put all the code into your theme's functions.php file.

You need to add a hook to your chat functions that are accessed via AJAX. There are two types of access - privileged and non-privileged. Here is how you add a hook:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_chat_function', 'my_chat_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_chat_function', 'my_chat_function');
```

Recently I completed a blog entry that could help you http://mehaul.me/blog/wordpress-using-ajax-to-query-posts/